# Crone configuration for weekly running

Tags: cron

can you, please, Write configuration cron line to run the script /root/backup.sh every Wednesday and Saturday at 19:13. Thank you!
Here is my code:

```
13 19 * * 3/6 root
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below will help you:

```
13  19  *  *  Wed,Sat  sh /root/backup.sh
```